# no such file of directory 'file.xml'

Tags: python, xml, zip

Having a small issues when trying to create a zip file using the `zipfile` module in python 3.

I have a directory which contains xml files, I am looking to create a zip archive from all these files in the same directory but keep encountering the error of `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] no such file or directory: 'file.xml'`

script:

```
import datetime
import os
import zipfile


path = '/Users/xxxx/reports/xxxx/monthly'
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%G'+'-'+'%B')
zf = os.path.join(path, '{}.zip'.format(month))

z = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w')
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith('.xml'):
        z.write(i)
z.close()
```

it seems like when `z.write(i)` is called it is looking in the working directory for the xml files however the working directory is `/Users/xxxx/scripts` where the python script is.

How would I get the `z.write(i)` to look at the `path` variable without changing the current working directory if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use os.chdir to move to the file path and try to write the files to zip.

```
import datetime
import os
import zipfile


path = '/Users/xxxx/reports/xxxx/monthly'
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%G'+'-'+'%B')
zf = os.path.join(path, '{}.zip'.format(month))

z = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w')
os.chdir(path)   #Change DIR
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith('.xml'):
        z.write(i)
z.close()
```

**Without changing DIR:**

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w')
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith('.xml'):
        z.write(os.path.join(path, i))
z.close()
```

Comment: using the `os.chdir(path)` changes the working directory, which in my case would change the staring directory for the loop that this is running inside, so I would need to do another `os.chdir(otherpath) back in the beginning of the script, this works but is there not another way that would not change the working directory ?

Comment: you can join the path instead of changing DIR. Updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

> What actually happens is that as you loop through `os.listdir(path)`, the `i` itself is simply the `FileName` which does not include the real `Path` to the File. There are a couple of ways to get around this; the simplest (*but crudest*) of which is shown below:

```
import datetime
import os
import zipfile

path    = '/Users/xxxx/reports/xxxx/monthly'
month   = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%G'+'-'+'%B')
zf      = os.path.join(path, '{}.zip'.format(month))
z       = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w')

for i in os.listdir(path):
    # DECLARE A VARIABLE TO HOLD THE FULL PATH TO THE FILE:
    xmlFile = "{}/{}".format(path, i)   # <== PATH TO CURRENT FILE UNDER CURSOR
    if xmlFile.endswith('.xml'):
        z.write(xmlFile)
        z.write(filename=xmlFile, arcname="ARCHIVE_NAME_HERE", ) # <== CHANGE
z.close()
```

Hope this Helps.
Cheers and Good-Luck...

Comment: This also works however I think the `z.write(i)` needs to be `z.write(xmlfile)` as it appeared it was giving the same error, how ever with the `z.write(xmlfile)` the zip file contained the entire path and not just the files.

Comment: @Marct  Precisely! Thanks for noting that.... `i` was now changed to `xmlFile`.... To get around the other issue, try adding the `arcname` Parameter. The Post was updated, taking the `arcname` Parameter into Account...